# How to use dynamic value for firebase cloud function configuration parameter: vpcConnector

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-vpc

I would like to create the following firebase cloud function:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const myCloudFunction = functions
    .runWith({vpcConnector: process.env.VPC_CONNECTOR})
    .region("asia-south1").https.onRequest(app);
```

However, when I deploy this function, it is not able to read the environment variable (which I have checked works fine in other places). I am getting the following error:

```
VPC connector projects/my-project/locations/asia-south1/connectors/undefined is not ready yet or does not exist.
```

However, if I provide a static value, i.e. `vpcConnector: "my-google-vpc"`, everything works fine!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like environment variables are not available when firebase tools is reading your code during deploy [[discussion](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/1084)]

I had to use firebase params to get the value for a VPC_CONNECTOR from environment variables:

```
const environment = defineString("MODE");
const vpcConnectorVar = defineString("VPC_CONNECTOR");
const vpcConnectorName = environment.equals("PRODUCTION")
    .thenElse(vpcConnectorVar, "");

export const myCloudFunction = functions
    .runWith({vpcConnector: vpcConnectorName})
    .region("asia-south1").https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, parameterized configuration variables need to be used. Like this:

```
const { defineString  } = require('firebase-functions/params');

const VPC_CONNECTOR = defineString('VPC_CONNECTOR');

export const myCloudFunction = functions
.runWith({vpcConnector: VPC_CONNECTOR})
.region("asia-south1").https.onRequest(app);
```

`VPC_CONNECTOR` should be configured in environments variables in console UI or using `.env.project-name` files before deployment.

When deploying a function with parameterized configuration variables, the Firebase CLI first attempts to load their values from local .env files (or from environment variables configured in the firebase functions console).